# What software is used to create the graphics for stuctural analysis textbooks?

Tags: cad, technical-drawing, drawings

I want to create some 2D and 3D drawings of simple trusses and frames. and I was wondering, what is the software used to create the graphics seen in structural analysis textbooks (example: R.C Hibbeler Structural Analysis and Ferdinand P. Beer Mechanics of Materials), such as these:

[image]

some graphics examples in this Imgur [album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCW7A.jpg)

Comment: Best to ask this on Academia SE

Comment: For many books it was a human, called a draughtsman. For the PC, draughtsperson.

Comment: Any graphic process software can do that - Paint, Paint Brush... as well as many 3D graphic generating software.

Comment: I agree, these are most likely drawn "by hand" - either literally or using a vector graphics package such as Adobe Illustrator.

Comment: Tip: add at least one image into your question. Not many readers are going to follow links just to understand your question.

Comment: Most like there was a technical illustrator that drew the images for the book. To this day they generally draw by hand. Similar example but for optics https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11926/periscope-camera-with-a-mobile-phone-how-to-make-walls-not-visible-on-the-camer/11941#11941 images drawn by hand in illustrator.